# How to upload file on another url folder

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am working on xampp localhost. I have a laravel setup. and I am uploading a file from my project to another laravel project.

```
public function cvupload(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
    'resume' => 'required|mimes:doc,pdf,docx'
    ],
    [
        'required' => 'This field is required',
        'mimes' => 'Allowed only doc,pdf,docx',
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('resume');
    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = 'http://example.com/adminapi/app/storage/uploads/';
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $resume_with_path = $destinationPath.$name;
}
```

i gives error

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException Unable to create the directory.
```

Comment: You have to create the directory of that project and give permission to save the pdf

Comment: Directory already is created and permission is 0755

Comment: First you save pdf in your own project. If it works then may be it cors problem too

Comment: yes saving in my own project.

Comment: Agree with @A.ANoman, might be a cors issue. Did you implement that method in the api routes file?

Comment: How to implement?

Comment: Basically my project and other project both are in same server. Only project folder is different. I need to upload file from my project folder to another project folder. That is why I gave complete URL.

Comment: give system path instead of url, such as `c:/xampp/htdocs/adminapi/<rest of path >` or create a URL at the other project that recieves a file, send the image to that url, and implement storage functionality in the other project.